# C snippet suddenly stops writing binary data to file

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char _binary_bin_start;
extern unsigned char _binary_bin_end;
extern unsigned char _binary_bin_size;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        unsigned char *pblob = &_binary_bin_start;

        int size = &_binary_bin_end - &_binary_bin_start;
        printf("size: %d\n", size);
        FILE *f = fopen("hello.bin", "wb");
        if(f==NULL){
                printf("file not opened");
        }else{
            int ret = fwrite(&_binary_bin_start, size, 1, f);
            fclose(f);
            printf("return val: %d\n", ret);
        }

}
```

I compile this then link with an object file of an executable binary created with objcopy. Yesterday everything was fine, the file hello.bin was created, filled with data and is executable after a chmod. Today it suddenly stopped getting populated with data - the file is sitting there at 0 bytes and there is no 'file not opened' message and the return value from fwrite is 1.

What could be the reason?

Comment: "...and the return value from fwrite is 1." - Ok, i'll bite, you know this *how*?

Comment: I wouldn't deduct the pointers of external chars to get the size, that's bad.

Comment: @Barmar `size` is equal to the binary size on disk.

Comment: @WhozCraig source updated.

Comment: @DavidOtano what should I do? It was working before.

Comment: Your program writes `hello.jar` but you expect `hello.bin`? Hmmm....

Comment: BTW: don't use identifiers with leading underscores, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Jens wrong version, updated.

Comment: If `size` is `> 1` then this `fwrite(&_binary_bin_start, size, 1, f);` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are basing the size on the difference in the addresses of two unsigned characters _binary_bin_start and _binary_bin_end and the actual runtime address of those variable could change from one run to the next.  Are these supposed to be unsigned char pointers to the front/end of some data buffer?

Comment: @alk what do you mean? `size` is 813.

Comment: @Jere binary object file created with `objcopy -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 bin bin.o` I then link this with the above script. The characters refer to this obj.

Comment: @user1561108: Conforming to the C-Standard reading past the end of an object invokes undefined behaviuor. `_binary_bin_start` is declared `char` so its size is 1. So reading more then 1 byte is reading beyond the end of the object, which provokes which then in turn undefined behaviour. Anything could happen afterwards.

Comment: @alk `_binary_bin_start` is the first byte of the binary file `bin` which has size 813. Like I said, the same code was working fine yesterday...

Comment: If a program runs into UB, anything could happend every time. The results are not necessarily predictable after having ran into Undefined Behaviuor.

Comment: @alk but the script reads no more than the size of the binary?

Comment: Could you provide the source defining those two externals `_binary_bin_start` and `_binary_bin_end` and how they are initialised?